# Pip installation of pyscipopt in windows

Tags: scip

I am trying to use SCIP solver for optimization. I am able to pip install the pyscipopt, but while trying to import I get the following error

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

How can I import pyscipopt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which module was not found? I guess it must be the `libscipopt.so`, right? Did you follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#installation-from-pypi), especially the bit about setting the `PATH` in Windows?

Comment: I think the problem is with adding the PATH. When I download the executables for Windows from http://scip.zib.de/ and run it, it doesn't seem to install any thing. I only get a cmd window saying "user parameter file <scip.set> not found -using default parameters". I don't know which location to add to the PATH variable.

Comment: Of course doesn't the executable install anything! It runs the solver. You need to download the library and when installing PySCIPOpt you need to tell the installer where this library can be found. You also need to download the headers as is explained in the GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. It was a little confusing in the beginning because I couldn't find header files. I later realized that there is a link for headers in the website http://scip.zib.de/#download.

Comment: Yeah, it can really be confusing. We're trying to improve the setup for the next version. Please use the Github page for questions about PySCIPOpt - if you have any.